# Trying to understand ASLR in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, aslr

Has something changed here? No matter whether I set `randomize_va_space`, the stack will always have an offset of 0. Afaik it should be a random number, right?

```
....                        
f7fd8000-f7fd9000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
f7fd9000-f7ffb000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 922294                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
f7ffb000-f7ffc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7ffc000-f7ffd000 r--p 00022000 08:05 922294                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
f7ffd000-f7ffe000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 922294                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
fffdd000-ffffe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
```

In other cases the stack is at a lower position tho:

```
...
7ffc2c7f6000-7ffc2c7f8000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc2c7f8000-7ffc2c7fa000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

But even in this case the offset is 0! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The starting and ending address `fffdd000-ffffe000` is what should change at every execution with ASLR enabled. You should see a different address here every time you run the program. The `00000000` is the offset in the file that this region was mapped from (which is not affected by ASLR) - if it wasn't mapped from a file, it is *always* 0.